# How to use a method to reference a data type(array) that is created in a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Sorry for the bad title...but I currently have a class Array and its constructor with a simple method getSize(). The constructor creates the array, is there a way to reference this array in the method without having to pass it as a param?

```
//constructor
Array(int n) {
    int arr[] = new int[n];
}
//method
static int getSize(int index) {

    //how do I reference the created array?
    return index;

}
```

SOLVED! THANK YOU

Comment: If you have that array `arr` declared as a field in your class, you should be able to reference it using, e.g., `arr.length`.

Comment: You need to look into [Class Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `getSize()` is declared `static` whereas `arr` seems to be a field.

Comment: @LuCio Didn't see that...but in that case it would only make sense for `arr` to also be static, I think.

Comment: I suggest you to read this tutorial [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to learn the difference between sttatic and non.static class memebers.

Comment: You need read more about class members here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 3):

You can not reference a local variable declared in another method.

Instead, you can make it an instance member and reference it in these two methods.

Also, `getSize` should not be `static` since you can not reference a `non-static` member in a `static` method.

```
private int arr[];

Array(int n) {
    arr[] = new int[n];
}

int getSize(int index) {
    //reference the array here
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not declare the array as a class variable?

```
int arr[];

//constructor
Array(int n) {
    arr = new int[n];
}
//method
int getSize(int index) {

    //how do I reference the created array?
    return index;

}
```

Comment: You may also want to consider statically creating the array as `getSize` is static

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes,but I think the OP had better to change his design

Comment: Thank you. I do plan on changing the design. This was just something I quickly typed up. But this solved it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access only the static variables in a static method. In order to access the array in this method either you have to make your array a static member but then you should initialize it in a static block.

Other thing which you can do is make the method non-static. Then you will be able to access the array inside the function without having to create an instance of the class.